# Access from classic resources to ARM storage account in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-networking, virtual-network, azure-storage

This is a generalised version of what I [posted on stack StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291450/allow-access-to-storage-account-from-old-cloud-service-classic-in-azure).

I have a number of storage accounts in Azure - the "new" ARM deployment model. I also have a number of old classic resources (VMs and Cloud Services) - using "old" ASM model.  There are reasons why these cannot be migrated to ARM at this time - the question is *not* about migration.

I am trying to configure the storage accounts to allow connections from only specified resources. I added our external on-prem addresses and I added virtual networks and subnets for other "new" ARM resources (VM, etc.)  However I'm struggling to allow classic resources to access the storage account.

I tried adding the external IP address of a classic resource - this didn't help, most likely, because internally within Azure (and these resources are within the same region) traffic is routed using some internal networks.  Note that I tried using both Microsoft routing and Internet routing - the result is exactly the same.

I tried adding these classic resources to a classic virtual network - but classic vnets are not even listed in the storage account configuration to select as an allowed private vnet.

As a result, the only option I have is to set "allow access from all networks", which isn't particularly secure.

Is there any way to restrict access to the storage account by networks/IP addresses *and* allow access from classic resources at the same time?